# How to change cursor puller background color on SearchView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got this white background on the cursor:

[image]

This searchview layouts on the appbarlayout:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/search_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                    android:id="@+id/organization_search_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:theme="@style/OrganizationSearchView"
                    app:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:submitBackground="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:elevation="8dp"
                    app:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_search"
                    app:voiceIcon="@drawable/ic_mic"/>

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/events_tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
                    app:tabTextColor="@color/white_70"
                    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabsTextAppearance"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/macaroni_and_cheese"
                    tools:layout_height="80dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

My searchview style (@style/OrganizationSearchView) :

```
<style name="OrganizationSearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black_40</item>
</style>
```

How can i remove white background color on cursor? Make it transparent for example

Answer (score 0):

Change `android:background` in your `OrganizationSearchView` style to transparent.

```xml
<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Then add `android:background="@android:color/white"` to your `SearchView` as given below

```xml
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:id="@+id/organization_search_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/OrganizationSearchView"
    app:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
    app:submitBackground="@android:color/transparent"
    app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    app:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_search"
    app:voiceIcon="@drawable/ic_mic"/>
```

[image]

Comment: @IliyaMashin Did u solve the issue? If not, check the updated answer

Comment: it's not worked for me. i just remove text select handler with empty drawable

        <item name="android:textSelectHandleLeft">@drawable/ic_cursor</item>
        <item name="android:textSelectHandleRight">@drawable/ic_cursor</item>
        <item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/ic_cursor</item>

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom ThemedSearchView

```
class ThemedSearchView @JvmOverloads constructor(
context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
, defTheme: Int = R.style.CustomSearchView
) : SearchView(ContextThemeWrapper(context, defTheme), attrs, defStyleAttr)
```

And you can apply your own theme then only to SearchView
This theme should have

```
<item name="android:background">@color/transparent</item>
```

Other colors are up to your choice, but cursor background will be transparent now.